# Name etymologies

Tags: discussion

Apologies if I overlooked an earlier discussion of this.

There were a couple of posts recently concerned with baby-naming and seeking advice on the etymologies of the OPs' chosen names. While these questions probably fall into the domain of etymology, I still have a feeling that they're not on topic here (neither do they strike me as high quality ones). Is it only me? If not, maybe we want to decide on a consistent policy towards them?

Comment: I think it's very rare to see a good etymology question of any kind... but I wouldn't know what to do to try to improve that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not just you. The main problem IMO is that until this is a full SE site, there is a limited set (3) of specific off-topic reasons allowed, and we're kind of full up. Name questions are usually not translation requests, or advice on learning a foreign language, or tree questions. IMO, the best approach for this class would be to revise the "translation" and "language specific" reasons. Questions generally get closed because they should be, and the reason given is the *closest* match to the actual reason, even if not precisely right.

Comment: Fair enough. Yes, I know about the restriction and feel like the existing ones should be redefined. By the way, is it long till this is a full site?